# Optimize the sum function over the an array elements using ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to optimize a sum of an array elements using ruby.

I started doing this:

```ruby
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = 0
numbers.each do | number |
  result = result + number
end
```

Later this:

```ruby
result = 0
[1,2,3,4].each do | n |
  result += n
end
```

And finally this:

```ruby
result = 0
[1,2,3,4].each { |value| result += value }
```

And Is possible to refactoring this a little more??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes*, like this:

```
result = [1,2,3,4].reduce(:+) # => 10
```

Comment: To preserve the behaviour of OP's code it should be `inject(0, :+)`, otherwise `[].inject(:+)` will return `nil`.

Comment: It works for other kind of functions like mult, division, etc.??

Comment: Sure (you can easily try that btw). See the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) for more info.

Comment: Just a question of taste and colors, but I prefer using `reduce` instead of `inject`. It does exactly the same, but for some reason it makes more sense to me :)